# JavaScript refactoring not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this bit of repeated code that toggles 2 radio button from being checked  in my `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#New").click(function () {
        var toggleOn = $("#New");
        var toggleOff = $("#Used");
        var value = true;

        toggleOn.prop("checked", value);
        toggleOn.val(value);
        toggleOff.prop("checked", !value);
        toggleOff.val(!value);
    });

    $("#Used").click(function () {
        var toggleOn = $("#Used");
        var toggleOff = $("#New");
        var value = true;

        toggleOn.prop("checked", value);
        toggleOn.val(value);
        toggleOff.prop("checked", !value);
        toggleOff.val(!value);
    });
});
```

I didn't want to have the repeated code so I refactored it into a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Used").on("click", toggleRadioButtons("Used", "New"));
    $("#New").on("click", toggleRadioButtons("New", "Used"));
});

function toggleRadioButtons(radioOne, radioTwo) {
    var toggleOn = $("#" + radioOne);
    var toggleOff = $("#" + radioTwo);
    var value = true;

    toggleOn.prop("checked", value);
    toggleOn.val(value);
    toggleOff.prop("checked", !value);
    toggleOff.val(!value);
}
```

So the problem is that with the refactored code the radio button is no longer properly unchecking the other radio button. I assuming it has to do with JavaScript closure but am not sure how that would apply since I am calling a function in it's outer scope.

Comment: `toggleRadioButtons("Used", "New")` is a **call** to the function.  You're passing the returned value (`undefined`) to `.on()`

Comment: `...on("click", () => toggleRadioButtons("Use...`

Comment: I think you are misusing radio buttons. Aren't native radio buttons with the same name supposed to only allow one selection. Do you want checkboxes instead?

Comment: 1 - You could be using radios with same name, so you can take advantage of native behavior of HTML....

2 - Try removing the "checked" attribute instead of setting as false ($().removeAttr())

Comment: Please show us your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give both radio buttons the same `name`, then only one will only be able to be selected at a time.

No need for jQuery at all.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<form name="car">
  <label>New  <input type="radio" name="condition" value="new" /></label>
  <label>Used <input type="radio" name="condition" value="used" /></label>
</form>
```

If you want them to be checkboxes, you can link them with a jQuery plugin. I called it `syncCheckboxes` and the code can be found below.

```js
(function($) {
  $.syncCheckboxes = function(...ids) {
    const $checkboxes = ids.map(id => $(id));
    $checkboxes.forEach(function($checkbox) {
      $checkbox.on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $checkboxes.forEach(function($curr) {
            $curr.prop('checked', $curr === $checkbox);
          });
        }
      })
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$.syncCheckboxes('#New', '#Used');
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="car">
  <label>New  <input type="checkbox" id="New"  value="new" /></label>
  <label>Used <input type="checkbox" id="Used" value="used" /></label>
</form>
```